# EOSJS error Non-base58 character

Tags: transactions, eosjs

Please help! I'm currently encountering the ff. error

> Uncaught Error: Non-base58 character
>       at Object.decode (eosjs-jssig.js:26)
>       at Object.checkDecode (eosjs-jssig.js:15)
>       at y (eosjs-jssig.js:15)
>       at Function.g.fromString (eosjs-jssig.js:15)
>       at new e (eosjs-jssig.js:15)
>       at displaybal:25

Here is a snapshot of my code

```
const defaultPrivateKey = "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr"; // bob
const addPrivateKey =     "EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4";
const rpc = new eosjs_jsonrpc.JsonRpc('http:///65.52.186.97:8888');
const signatureProvider = new eosjs_jssig.JsSignatureProvider([addPrivateKey]);
const api = new eosjs_api.Api({ rpc, signatureProvider, textDecoder: new TextDecoder(), textEncoder: new TextEncoder() });

(async () => {
try {
const result = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
        account: 'eosio',
        name: 'newaccount',
        authorization: [{
        actor: 'eosio',
        permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
        creator: 'eosio',
        name: 'testnewaccount',
        owner: {
            threshold: 1,
            keys: [{
            key: 'EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4',
            weight: 1
            }],
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
        },
        active: {
            threshold: 1,
            keys: [{
            key: 'EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4',
            weight: 1
            }],
            accounts: [],
            waits: []
        },
        },
    }]
    }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
    });
  console.log(result);
} catch (e) {
  returnmsg = '\nCaught exception: ' + e;
  if (e instanceof eosjs_jsonrpc.RpcError)
  returnmsg += '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2);
  console.log(returnmsg);
}
  })();
```

My tools are

> Angular CLI: 7.3.8
>   Node: 10.15.3
>   Angular: 7.2.12
>   Windows 10
>   chrome
>   Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

You `addPrivateKey` is pointing to a public key instead of a private one. JSSignatureProvider expect a private key